# Expanding-Collapsable HTML List- ul - li - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html-lists

I am implementing a ul and li list, from json data and with expand/collapse function.

The problem is that when trying the expand/collapse, all the subitems are expanding together, but i want only the clicked one to be collapsed/expanded;

Here is my code :

```
<html>
   <head>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
      <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <style type="text/css">
         ul li ul {
         display: none;
         } 
         a {
         color: red;
         }
      </style>
      <title></title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <ul id="menu" class="list">
      </ul>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         $(window)
                 .load(
                         function() {
                             var JSON = {
                                 menu : [ {
                                     name : 'Title',
                                     link : '#',
                                     sub : [ {
                                         name : 'Enclosure1',
                                         link : '#',
                                         sub : null
                                     }, {
                                         name : 'Enclosure2',
                                         link : '#',
                                         sub : null
                                     }, {
                                         name : 'Enclosure3',
                                         link : '#',
                                         sub : null
                                     } ]
                                 },{
                                     name : 'Link',
                                     link : '#',
                                     sub : null
                                 },{
                                     name : 'Content',
                                     link : '#',
                                     sub : null
                                 },{
                                     name : 'Enclosures',
                                     link : '#',
                                     sub : [ {
                                         name : 'Enclosure1',
                                         link : '#',
                                         sub : null
                                     }, {
                                         name : 'Enclosure2',
                                         link : '#',
                                         sub : null
                                     }, {
                                         name : 'Enclosure3',
                                         link : '#',
                                         sub : null
                                     } ]
                                 }, {
                                     name : 'Authors',
                                     link : '#',
                                     sub : [ {
                                         name : 'Author1',
                                         link : '#',
                                         sub : null
                                     }, {
                                         name : 'Author2',
                                         link : '#',
                                         sub : null
                                     } ]
                                 },{
                                     name : 'Published At',
                                     link : '#',
                                     sub : null
                                 }, {
                                     name : 'Stream',
                                     link : '#',
                                     sub : [ {
                                         name : 'STR1',
                                         link : '#',
                                         sub : null
                                     }, {
                                         name : 'STR2',
                                         link : '#',
                                         sub : null
                                     } ]
                                 } ]
                             }

                             $(function() {

                                 function parseMenu(ul, menu) {
                                     for (var i = 0; i < menu.length; i++) {
                                         var li = $(ul).append(
                                                 '<li>'+ menu[i].name
                                                         + '</li>');
                                         if (menu[i].sub != null) {
                                             var subul = $('<ul class="list"></ul>');
                                             $(li).append(subul);
                                             parseMenu($(subul), menu[i].sub);
                                                 }
                                     }
                                 }

                                 var menu = $('#menu');
                                 parseMenu(menu, JSON.menu);
                             });
                         });//]]>​
      </script>
      <script type="text/javascript">$(document).on('click', '.list > li ', function () {
         $(this).parent().children('ul').toggle();
         })
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31508500/dead-simple-collapsable-list-function-for-deep-and-shallow-nested-ul-li-lists-j

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your script , change to toggle the "next" UL tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript">$(document).on('click', '.list > li ', function () {
    $(this).next('ul').toggle();
})</script>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xgoapR

And to start with submenu collapsed, change

```
ul li ul {
         display: none;
         }
```

to

```
ul >  ul {
    display: none;
}
```

EDIT:
Check a full working example with collapse, animation, and +/- toggle in
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mWbLpm

Comment: working fine ! but i want the list to be closed in default (not expanded in default)

Comment: I added a CSS fix to start with collapsed items

Comment: Great !! thank you, what about the sub-lists, how can i do to customize their fonts and size ?

Comment: Customize sub-lists Adding CSS rules for `.list > ul > li` or `#menu > ul >li`

Comment: Great ! and what about adding a slide down animation between lists and sublists ?

Comment: Simply add a "timer" parameter in `toggle()`, for example `toggle(200)`.You can find more options in http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: Great !! Thank you !! a final thing, is that i want to kind of indicate whether any of my members have a sublist or not (kind of a left shadow to tell whether this list is expandable (has children) or not) ? do you have any idea ?)

Comment: See http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VpZMbQ, line 128 for adding a class name to LI with sublist, and line 23 for adding a CSS class for .multi . You can use some special character (only text) in `content` property

Comment: Yes, but it works only on the first level, with sublist of sublists, it doesn't work !

Comment: Change `#menu > .multi::after` (only for fisrt level) for a more generic style `ul > .multi::after`. The example doesn't have multiple  levels.

Comment: Yapp it's working ! and if i want to change the character once i click on a member, how can i do ? (from a '+' to a '-')

Comment: Check in http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mWbLpm. Toggle a "opened" class in the click event, add `$(this).toggleClass('multi-opened');` and create a css rule for `ul > .multi-opened::after` with content ' -'

Answer (score 2):

checkout this one, there is a small validation problem with your code, you can not have ul inside ul, but you can put it inside li.

```js
var JSON = {
  menu: [{
    name: "Title",
    link: "#",
    sub: [{
      name: "Enclosure1",
      link: "#",
      sub: null
    }, {
      name: "Enclosure2",
      link: "#",
      sub: null
    }, {
      name: "Enclosure3",
      link: "#",
      sub: null
    }]
  }, {
    name: "Link",
    link: "#",
    sub: null
  }, {
    name: "Content",
    link: "#",
    sub: null
  }, {
    name: "Enclosures",
    link: "#",
    sub: [{
      name: "Enclosure1",
      link: "#",
      sub: null
    }, {
      name: "Enclosure2",
      link: "#",
      sub: null
    }, {
      name: "Enclosure3",
      link: "#",
      sub: null
    }]
  }, {
    name: "Authors",
    link: "#",
    sub: [{
      name: "Author1",
      link: "#",
      sub: null
    }, {
      name: "Author2",
      link: "#",
      sub: null
    }]
  }, {
    name: "Published At",
    link: "#",
    sub: null
  }, {
    name: "Stream",
    link: "#",
    sub: [{
      name: "STR1",
      link: "#",
      sub: null
    }, {
      name: "STR2",
      link: "#",
      sub: null
    }]
  }]
};


$(function() {

  function parseMenu(ul, menu) {
    for (var i = 0; i < menu.length; i++) {
      var li = $(ul).append(
        '<li>' + menu[i].name + '</li>');
      if (menu[i].sub != null) {
        var subul = $('<ul class="list"></ul>');
        $(li).append(subul);
        parseMenu($(subul), menu[i].sub);
      }
    }
  }

  var menu = $('#menu');
  parseMenu(menu, JSON.menu);
});



$(document).on('click', '.list > li ', function() {
  $(this).next('ul').toggle();
});
```

```css
ul ul {
  display: none;
}

a {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="menu" class="list"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick fix would be to replace last script with this snippet:

```
<script type="text/javascript">$(document).on('click', '.list > li ', function () {
$(this).next('.list').children().toggle();
})</script>
```

What this will do is expand and collapse the list that is right after your heading element.

A better solution would be to restructure your HTML DOM content by creating nested "ul" under "li".

Hope this helps.