# dependencies for dead simple collapsible lists

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, dependencies

I expect there are obvious dependencies for the delightful bit of code provided here ([Dead simple Collapsable List Function for deep and shallow nested UL/LI lists (JQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31508500/dead-simple-collapsable-list-function-for-deep-and-shallow-nested-ul-li-lists-j)), but unfortunately it isn't obvious to me what those dependencies are

I am linking to the jquery-3.2.1.min.js library, but do I need other libraries too?

Thanks, the solution seems delightful

+J

Comment: There is no other dependency. What is your problem with this code?

Comment: Thanks. Well it only shows the first item in the list, and nothing happens when I click on it. I'm not much of a js programmer

Comment: That is certainly due to `:first` in `.children(":first")`. Post the HTML you want to animate if you want a more precise answer.

Comment: Thanks. I'm sure I'm stupidly missing something simple

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="scripts/style.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/clickFunction.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <ul>
   <li>1.1</li>
   <ul>
    <li>1.1.1</li>
    <li>1.1.2</li>
    <li>1.1.2</li>
   </ul>
   <li>1.2</li>
   <li>1.3</li>
  </ul>
  <li>2</li>
  <ul>
   <li>2.1</li>
   <li>2.2</li>
   <li>2.3</li>
  </ul>
</ul>
</body>
</html>

Comment: The HTML list structure is incorrect in what you provided in comment.

Comment: Thanks - will correct

Comment: I think I know what I did wrong. Thanks!

Comment: I've tried fixing the HTML list structure, but I'm getting nowhere. I tried deleting my own HTML list and pasting yours in there, but it still doesn't work. May I send my code to your email address?